# Routes not found or constructed incorrectly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2, localization, routes

The following is my routes definition from global.asax.cs:

```
routes.Add(
  new NamedTypedRoute(
    "feedback-en", RouteType.Regular, "{culture}/Feedback",
    new RouteValueDictionary(
      new
      {
        culture = "en",
        controller = "Feedback",
        action = "Index"
      }
    ),
    null,
    new MultiLingualMvcRouteHandler()
  )
);

routes.Add(
  new NamedTypedRoute(
    "feedback-sl", RouteType.Regular, "{culture}/Kontakt",
    new RouteValueDictionary(
      new
      {
        culture = "sl",
        controller = "Feedback",
        action = "Index"
      }
    ),
    null,
    new MultiLingualMvcRouteHandler()
  )
);
```

If I do this in the view

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("sl", "feedback-sl")%> | <%: Html.ActionLink("en", "feedback-en")%>
```

the constructed URL points to the root site (no controller/action information is included in the constructed link).

If I do this in the view

```
<%: Html.RouteLink("sl", "feedback-sl")%> | <%: Html.RouteLink("en", "feedback-en")%>
```

an exception occurs:

```
"A route named 'feedback-sl' could not be found in the route collection.
Parameter name: name"
```

My two questions:

1. Why are there two very similar helpers, RouteLink and ActionLink? What's the difference between them?
2. I guess there could be something wrong with my NamedTypedRoute implementation. I need this to have named routes and typed routes - route can be admin and regular. I use this information to dynamically  construct administration menu based on routes definition. For administration pages, I have names pointing to resource strings and then I use those names in administration page titles. That way I have localizable route names. Am I overcomplicating this ??

Comment: Could you please share with us the implementation of `NamedTypedRoute` and `MultiLingualMvcRouteHandler`? There may be an issue with one of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html.ActionLink extension renders an anchor element that links to an action. Html.RouteLink extension on the other hand renders an anchor element which could resolve to an action method, a file, a folder, or some other resource. The RouteLink doesn't really take ActionName and ControllerName strings like the ActionLink. From more detail look a bit at the parameter names for the parameters. The descriptions here are not really well written in MSDN/IntelliSense.

Sadly I don't have an answer for the second question.